# Oracle IMPDP into table with different column order

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I am using APPEND option of IMPDP to import into an existing table. ( APPEND option adds rows to an existing table).

Though the columns on source and target are same - the order of columns is different.

Will IMPDP take care of this ?

Comment: Yes, impdp will take care of that. The generated DML insert statements will define their own column order.

Comment: On the same note - if the source table has 40 columns and target 35, can the EXPDP copy just a subset of columns ?

Comment: No, use sqlldr for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rearranging column orders.

When you make an invisible column visible, the column is included in the table's column order as the last column.

Example
Create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    a INT,
    b INT,
    d INT,
    e INT
);
```

Add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD (c INT);
```

Move the column to the middle:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY (d INVISIBLE, e INVISIBLE);
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY (d VISIBLE, e VISIBLE);
DESCRIBE t;

Name
----
A
B
C
D
E
```